# What is a good hosting solution for running node.js with R / Rserve?

Tags: r, node.js, heroku

I need to run R with Node.js, using Rio (https://github.com/albertosantini/node-rio) as the node binding to Rserve.

I like Heroku but this seems like it is pushing the Heroku envelope beyond what it or I am competent with:

I've looked briefly into installing a custom buildpack

https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r

to run simultaneously with node.js:

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

This all seems pretty scary. Anyone got any good advice for how best to host this? My app works just fine locally.

Comment: Maybe this will be of help: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#installation (if not ignore the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and recommendations from Heroku, I believe the Heroku solution would be

Use https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r

in combination with

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi#readme

to build a multi build pack.

Answer (score 4):

http://prgmr.com/xen/

I currently use this solution to run my Node.js server and it's currently great.
They have wonderful support and they're uptime is 100%. I cannot recommend this any higher, but you will need to know how to set up a simple OS and run it from the ground up.

For example, if you want to run a server without having it stop when you close the SSH connection, you would use `screen node script.js` and press [control] + [A] + [D] keys.

You might already know this, so simply take my advice and view the [website](http://prgmr.com/xen/).